# Use of なら that are not "if"

Tags: grammar, particles

I recently saw a subbed video of two Seiyuus having a conversation where they say this phrase:

"金ならあるし"

Which was subbed as "Well I have money anyways"

The context was they were talking about a catchphrase one of them will have in the future.

I often see なら being used as "if" or a conditional phrase but it doesn't seem like it here.

Does it have other uses besides "if"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Xなら is still basically a conditional expression. You can translate it using conditionals like "If X is what matters", "If it's about X", "If you mean X", "If X is the case", "If you worry about X", and so on. For example, それなら is typically translated as "If so" or "If that's the case".

金ならあるし can be understood along the lines of "If money matters, I have some". In this case, the difference between 金ならあるし and 金はあるし is probably not very important, so it's okay to translate the なら as just an emphatic version of は.

Answer (score 3):

[なら](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89) can mean *as for, on the topic of*.  So the sentence means literally, *as for money, I have it*.